# Maximum recursion depth exceeded when creating subclass of pygame.sprite.Sprite

Tags: python, recursion, pygame, sprite, subclass

I am trying to instanciate a object i created witch is a subclass of pygame.sprite.Sprite. This is the code i use to instanciate it:

```
    import pygame as pg
    from GameObject import GameObject    

    player = GameObject("Sprites/Player", 6)
```

And this is the code for the object itself:

```
import pygame as pg
class GameObject(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __ini__(self, image_path, number_of_images):
        for i in range(number_of_images):
            self.images.append(pg.image.load("{}/sprite{}.png".format(image_path, i)))
```

When i try to run it i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    player = GameObject("Sprites/Player", 6)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 142, in add
    self.add(*group)
  [Previous line repeated 327 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I have looked at sever example codes for creating a subclass of this class but i do not see the difference between my code and others. What am i missing out on?

Comment: is this your whole code? Based on that stack trace it looks like your __ini__ function is calling itself but I don't see that happening in your code

Comment: This is all the code, yes. Do you mean \_\_init\_\_? It seems like it is called automaticly since it is the constructor of the superclass.

Comment: This line  `def __ini__(self, image_path, number_of_images):` is what I'm referring to. maximum recursion depth exceeded means you have a function that calls itself too many times. Recursion is essentially just a function that calls itself, so you need to look through your code and find where that is happening to fix this

Comment: As I said, this is all my code and when I try to place prints to look where this recursion is I find that it is in the line where create the object but before the \_\_init\_\_ I created dose anything. If you look at the error message you can see that the recursion happens in the sprite-object I'm pygame, not anything I wrote so I must be calling it wrong or something

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change `__ini__` to `__init__`?

Comment: Oh, my.. that is awkward.. I will try

Comment: It fixed it! Thanks and sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it's caused by the typo in the `__init__` (you wrote `__ini__`) function (it happened to me when i wrote `_init_` instead of `__init__`).
Fixing the typo makes it work